# Event not triggered in MVP Supervising Controller

Tags: c#, design-patterns, mvp

I have create abstract class for Presenter

```
public abstract class MvpPresenter<T>
{
    public T View { get; set; }

    public MvpPresenter()
    {
    }

    public MvpPresenter(T view)
    {
        View = view;
    }
}
```

and UserPresenter class that inherit from abstract Presenter

```
public class UserPresenter2 : MvpPresenter<IUserView>
{
    private void OnUserSave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (View.ContextData.IsDirty)
        {
            User user = new User();

            User domainUser = DataMapper.Translate(View.ContextData);
            new UserServiceStub().SaveUser(domainUser);
        }
    }

    private void OnUserSearch(object sender, SearchEventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.SearchCriteria))
        {
            View.StatusMessage = "User name can not be null";
            return;
        }

        User user = new UserServiceStub().GetUser(e.SearchCriteria);
        if (user == null)
        {
            View.StatusMessage = String.Format(
                "There's no user found for user name:{0}", e.SearchCriteria);
            return;
        }

        UserDTO userDTO = DataMapper.Translate(user);
        View.ContextData = userDTO;
    }
}
```

code for view:

```
 public abstract class MvpView<TPresenter, TView> : Page
    where TPresenter : MvpPresenter<TView>
{
    public TPresenter Presenter { get; set; }

    public MvpView()
        : base()
    {
        if (!(this is TView))
            throw new Exception("MvpView must implement the interface provider as generic TView type");

        // Create and initialize presenter
        Presenter = Activator.CreateInstance<TPresenter>();
        Presenter.View = (TView)((object)this);
    }
}
```

the problem is when user click search, the page didn't response. I know that search event has not registered yet with the View, but I cannot do it in constructor.

Comment: Why can't you not do it in the constructor?

Comment: I have tried, but still error "No parameterless constructor defined for this object"

Comment: Can you post the code for the View? It seems you might not be constructing it correctly. However, I was suggesting you register the events in the Presenter constructor, after passing the View instance.

Comment: @rae1n, no problem I have added code for the view. Actually, the idea is to create a generic framework of mvp. So, it doesn't need to inject view into presenter.